# Variable Date Ranged Data Sets with SQL Statement? Used with MS Access Tables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have some large series of datasets. That is why when imported, they are automatically divided into tables by year.

EX: Data is from 2014, it goes into table "2014"
If Data is from 2013, it goes into table "2013", all on its own. If the table does not exist, it creates the table, and also inserts "2014" in tblYears to keep track of the tables that have been created.

My issue: I'm trying to allow the user to be able to look-up date ranges of the data. So Maybe someone wants to see Data spanning across February 2013 to March 2015.

So I'm sure I can find a SQL query with a WHERE clause to look-up only the data within the Date Range the user gives, however my issue arises if the date range spans across multiple years. How do I tell the SQL statement to Include all the tables? Let's say someone has a date range of 2013, 2014, and 2015. How do I make sure (variably speaking) that it can include all tables in the FROM?

Comment: you can use the `UNION` operator but what normal people would do is put all the info in a single table with a `Year` column to distinguish them... you can't change the structure?

Comment: It's a large clump of data to be putting in 1 MS Access table is the issue - thats why I'm separating by year currently :(

I know I can use the UNION, but the years are going to be variable based on what the user enters. The Year span could range 2 years, it could range 10 years.

Comment: it doesn't matter if it's a big clump of data. you can always use queries if you need to edit the information.

Comment: A MS Access Table isn't the same as a SQL Database.

Comment: yeah but how many records are you talking about, hundreds of thousands? millions? if you're bumping up against the limit why use Access?

Comment: I don't see why you need this design. The maximum size for a recordset is 1 GB. the max size for an accdb is 2 GB. If you are hitting these you have a lot a lot of data. How many records do you have per year/total?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a query of the relevant years every time the user opens the DB. That way if years are added it is always there. and since it is dropped/recreated every time they open the file it is always up to date.

Something like

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qNewUnion As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rsYears As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlUnion As String, unionAllString As String, unionQueryName As String

unionQueryName = "AllResultYears"
unionAllString = " Union All "

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsYears = db.OpenRecordset("Your years Table")

'make all your union sql using relevant years
Do While Not rsYears.EOF
    sqlUnion = sqlUnion & vbNewLine & " Select * from Results_" & rsYears("Year") & unionAllString
    rsYears.MoveNext
Loop
rsYears.Close

'lop off that trailing Union All
sqlUnion = Left(sqlUnion, Len(sqlUnion) - Len(unionAllString))

Set qNewUnion = New QueryDef
qNewUnion.SQL = sqlUnion
qNewUnion.Name = unionQueryName

'delete this query if it already exists
On Error Resume Next
db.QueryDefs.Delete unionQueryName
On Error GoTo 0

'add your new query
db.QueryDefs.Append qNewUnion
```

Then you use this `AllResultYears` query as the basis for your search.

Of course this will be much more expensive that just putting your data in one table. That's the optimal solution.